# Include local images in RDoc

Tags: ruby, image, documentation, rdoc

I have created an image with a "visual" tool that I want to include on the front page of my rdoc documentation. The front page is defined in a *.rdoc . I have found it possible to include external images but how do I include local ones?

Update: a work around is to add html for the image without the double quotes: `<img src=../../images/overview.jpg>` if the image is in the images folder in the root directory. (Assuming generating rdoc to some folder in the same folder.) A proper `/>` ending does not work either. The `/` gets added to the url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
rdoc-image:relative/path/to/image.png
```

in `*.rdoc` is converted to

```
<img src="relative/path/to/image.png">
```

in `*.html`, which works for me.

Reference:

- http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.1.0/RDoc/Markup.html#class-RDoc::Markup-label-Links

Answer (score 0):

You could try to embed inline images into the docs maybe?

Use something like this:

https://github.com/sdsykes/fastimage

Comment: but not without tweaking rdoc?

Comment: you could generate the inline code with fastimage, and then paste it into your image link.

Comment: interesting - not sure I would like that kind of roundtrip but still a useful pointer!